# MYSQL, how can I get rows in conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by, sql-null

I have a structure `role_approvers`:

```
id, role_id, level, user_id, approval_date
```

Rows:

```
4116, 1300, 1, 1158, 2021-05-28 14:24:34
4117, 1300, 1, 1186, NULL
4596, 1300, 2, 21, NULL
```

I need to get MIN level where role_id = 1300 and ALL approval_date on this level should be NULL

So in this case I need to get level = 2, but I don't know how to get it, can someone help with a query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the table for `role_id = 1300`, group by `level`, set the condition in the `HAVING` clause that all dates are `null` and return the top level:

```
SELECT level
FROM role_approvers
WHERE role_id = 1300
GROUP BY level
HAVING MAX(approval_date) IS NULL
ORDER BY level LIMIT 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8ff38c52e4c55e3af3fbcff2bf9d98da).